# programmatic scrolling of 2 divs separately

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 scrollable div containing objects with ids
I am trying to visually align - where obj and ff are in different divs

```
var el = document.getElementById(obj);
el.scrollIntoView(true);
var el = document.getElementById(ff);
el.scrollIntoView(true);
```

What happens now is that scrolling is not specific to the div holding the object.
That is, scrolling is on both divs simultaneously.
I want to be able scroll the objects in the divs separately, hopefully using only `Javascript/CSS.`
Hope this is sufficient.
ADDED: FIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/wTjR6/2/ in this example obj and ff should end up on the same horizontal level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to set the scrollTop property of the div container.

```
// JavaScript
var el = document.getElementById("obj");
el.parentNode.scrollTop = el.offsetTop - 5;

// jQuery
$("#ff").parent().scrollTop($("#ff").offset().top - 5);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wTjR6/1/

Comment: [offsetting objects](http://jsfiddle.net/wTjR6/2/) umm, by making the objects offset it appears that the scrolling is not separate.

Comment: What do you mean by "not separate"? I am under the impression that you want to scroll to the object in its parent container?

Comment: sorry, meant to add thanks for the prompt reply but posted instead. the end result should be ff and obj on the same horizontal level. Hope that helps

Comment: I see. We have it set so that it scrolls the object to the top of the parent. The "ff" object is at the bottom of the parent, so we can't scroll it to the top (there is nothing under "ff" to fill that space). You can set it so that it scrolls the object to the bottom of the parent, but you'll run into the same issue if an object is at the top of the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/wTjR6/5/

Comment: newbe error, added additional filler and works as advertised. Many thanks this save a whole lot of trouble.